# Cordova opening and closing a new window

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, memory-leaks, mobile-safari, html

There is a memory leak in Safari that is causing problems with my cordova app.  I am using the WebAudio Api and it would seem that the the browser is not handling garbage collection correctly.  So after much investigation I found somebody who had a similar problem and their solution was to play/ record sounds in an iframe and then destroy the iframe. https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues/102

```
I have successfully found a fix for this issue, and it's a hacky one :+1:

So after some experimentation , I discovered this bug is due to mobile safari, not soundjs. Whilst disabling sounds on ipad for our webapp (to prevent memory leaks and the eventual crash), I accidentally discovered that sounds created in an iframe were being correctly cleaned up.

The solution is simple, whenever a sound is played, create it in a script within an iframe. When you are done, destroy that iframe. I changed my old test to confirm this (the old one crashed at 34 plays):

http://files.dubitlimited.com/sjsiframetest/
```

However, in my solution I am using some native functionality (I need to access the file system to get one of the sounds) together with some WebAudio Api functions. What I want to do is open the iframe, access the file system, mix my two recordings together, save them to the file system, and then delete the iframe.  This will hopefully overcome my memory leak.  I did manage to test it a couple of weeks ago, and managed to get it to work, but can't for the life of me remember how.

Now when I return to it, I am having trouble initializing the app on the newly created iframe.  Without the app initialized I can't access any of the cordova functions like 'LocalFileSystem'.  Every time I try to initialise the app within the iframe I receive an error **deviceready has not fired after 5 
seconds**

I've also looked at trying to load the html page separately `<a href="record.html" data-ajax="false">RECORD</a>`  but I can't seem to initialise that page either.

The record html page looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Record</title>
</head>

<body onload="createAudioContext();">
Test Iframe
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ici_pici.js"></script>
<script> app.initialize();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that the recommendation is to have a single page app, and therefore by trying to load a seperate page is against best practice, but I need to overcome this memory leak, and the only way I can see to do it is to have the function called from a window that I can later destroy.

Any advice of how I can approach this?

Thanks

Comment: "Safari Opera" -- you mean Webkit Opera?

Comment: Oh sorry I'm not 100% sure actually.  I debug the app externally on Safari.  It is a Cordova app on IOS so I think its web view is Safari?  But I'm not sure.